# how to remove scroll bars inrrespective of the browser height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm designing a website in which i dont want to have any vertical scrollbars and make the page completely filled. The page consists of divs and images inside them. I can resize the image depending on the div's dimensions.

I looked at css media queries, but I cannot use ranges here, as I have to use exact screen height and put divs appropriately. How to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your idea of how to do this is more complicated than how it really is. :D I've always stuck to just declaring `overflow:hidden` via CSS on the `body` element to remove vertical scrollbars.

Comment: no i have to show the all of the content. But somehow dynamically resize

Comment: You're talking about fluid layouts here. `overflow:hidden` hides the scrollbars --- it's your job then to write the CSS to make your content adjust to the given space so that everything is still shown.